# Groovy java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://

Tags: windows, jdbc, groovy, mssql-jdbc

I am quite new to groovy and am quite confused about the Groovy `java.sql.SQLException` that I'm getting.

Here is my code

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
@Grapes(
        @Grab(group='com.microsoft.sqlserver', module='mssql-jdbc', version='7.2.2.jre8')
)

import groovy.sql.*
 
def username = xxx, password = yyy
 
// Create connection to MSSQL with classic JDBC DriverManager.
def db = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=tempdb;", username, password, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
```

The same SQL JDBC Connection string (`"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=tempdb;",  'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'`) works just fine for my other cases, like Java or JMeter, but not works with groovy. This is what I'm getting:

```
> groovy groovy-sql-test.groovy
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512M -Xmx1g
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=tempdb;
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=tempdb;
        at groovy-sql-0.run(groovy-sql-0.groovy:11)
```

This is running under Win10.

I've also tried

`groovy -cp D:\path\to\my\jars groovy-sql-test.groovy`

where within the `D:\path\to\my\jars` dir, I'm having both `sqljdbc41.jar` and `mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar` files.

Comment: Have you tried with `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)` ?

Comment: BINGO!!! Thanks a thousand @cfrick!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)` to use the system
classloader and thus get the jdbc driver picked up.

From https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_connecting_using_grab

> The `@GrabConfig` statement is necessary to make sure the system
> classloader is used. This ensures that the driver classes and system
> classes like `java.sql.DriverManager` are in the same classloader.